# Ubuntu recovery mode

Tags: dual-boot

I have dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8 on my computer. So recently I accidentally removed some important packages from my ubuntu and now when I try to load Ubuntu from the GRUB list, it boots up only as a terminal.

I tried to boot Ubuntu in recovery mode, but the recovery menu does not show up also. Even the recovery mode boots into a terminal shell.

Please someone help. I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem getting into recovery mode, have you tried using the escape key rather than the shift key during boot-up? The whole internet says that it is the shift key, but it only worked for me when I pressed the escape key. Then from there, a dpkg tool is there for broken packages and you can open a shell as root if you have lost any privileges. Besides this I'm not sure what else to say but good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look what was removed:

```
grep 'remove ' /var/log/dpkg.log | less
```

(if the logs are already rotated, then look inside dpkg.log.1, dpkg.log.2.gz, dpkg.log.3.gz, etc.)

Dump it into file:

```
grep 'remove ' /var/log/dpkg.log > ~/removed-dpkg.log
```

Then manually delete the lines from that file that are not related to the time when you removed the packages. Or you can instead select relevant lines with *grep* and specific date:

```
grep '2015-04-23 21:27' ~/removed-dpkg.log > to-restore-dpkg.log
```

Then do the test run of installing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{if($3=="remove")print $4}' ~/to-restore-dpkg.log | xargs sudo apt-get --dry-run install
```

Delete the *--dry-run* option to actually do the install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

However, the last command you passed me did not work. I'm sure I did all the other steps correctly, but when I try to run that one, shows several errors saying that it was unable to locate package packages.

Is there another way to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Have you deleted that space from **grep 'remove '** command? It was preventing the line like "2015-03-13 22:57:27 startup packages remove". I've changed last command to do that check too.